# Get kubernetes credentials from Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-machine, kubectl

- I have created a `Azure container Service`

`orchestratorType : Kubernetes
Group-Name : Mygrp
DNS : MyDNs`

- Now I have to install kubectl on m/c and service , pods too
- For this I logged into my account from `azure CLI`
- I need azure kubernetes credentials for `kubectl` and command for taht is

`az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=<cluster-resource-group> --name=<cluster-name>`

- From above Info , I know `cluster-resource-group` is `Mygrp` (or I am wrong ?) but what will be `cluster-name` ?

  - Or their is something I have configure for this  ?

Comment: `--name` you can find it in Azure portal, in that resource group we can find it . you can use this command to list it `az acs list -g Mygrp`

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT ok. I got  the name in result json, using that I eran the command again but now this error `AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.` . But since I am able to `az acs list -g Mygrp` command then by not other ?

Comment: Have you login Azure CLI 2.0?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT azure-cli (2.0.6)

Comment: We should login CLI 2.0 with this command `az login -u yourazureaccount -p yourpassword`

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT yeah I am already logged in , and I am able to run other commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145093/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-user5594493).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the `--name` via Azure Portal:

[image]

Comment: How can one disconnect from `Azure kubernetes` machine ?
Because now Everytime I run any `kuberctl` command , it interacts with `Azure Kubernetes` machine and I wanted to do some RnD on my local machine before pushing them on azure .

Comment: Do you mean you want to run kubectl on your local machine, don't apply for Azure ACS?

Comment: yeah , I have kubernetes installed on my local machine (off course that will not assign exteral IP to my service but just want to test my scripts and env to see if pods/services are created) , now azure ACS credentials are stored in kube config , so kubctl only connect with Azure ACS

Comment: I see, let me try, please wait for a while. by the way, to get more help, you'd better ask a new question here, and I will take it :)

Comment: I was thinking about the new question but not sure what must be the title of question , anyway here it is 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195652/disconnect-with-azure-acs-form-local-machine

Comment: @user5594493 Please check my answer, let me know if you would like further assistance.