# Disconnect with Azure ACS form Local Machine

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-machine, kubectl

- I had pull my `azure acs` credentials using below command and I can communicate with `kubernetes machine` on Azure from my local machine

  `az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=<cluster-resource-group> --name=<cluster-name>`
- But Now I wanted to disconnect this connection so that my kubctl can connect with other machine , it can be local or any other machine  (I am trying to connect with local).
- But everytime I ran `kubectl  command` it communicate with `Azure ACS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your scenario, we can use `kubectl config use-context CONTEXT_NAME` to switch default cluster to others, in this way, we can switch to another k8s cluster.
We can use this command to list k8s contexts:

```
root@shui:~# kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME               CLUSTER            AUTHINFO                 NAMESPACE
          jasontest321mgmt   jasontest321mgmt   jasontest321mgmt-admin   
*         jasonk8s321mgmt    jasonk8s321mgmt    jasonk8s321mgmt-admin
```

Specify k8s cluster name, we can use this command`kubectl config use-context CONTEXT_NAME`:

```
root@shui:~# kubectl config use-context -h
Sets the current-context in a kubeconfig file

Examples:
  # Use the context for the minikube cluster
  kubectl config use-context minikube

Usage:
  kubectl config use-context CONTEXT_NAME [options]
```

For example:

```
root@shui:~# kubectl config use-context jasontest321mgmt
Switched to context "jasontest321mgmt".
```